# an isomorphism: $H^{q-1}(G,C) \xrightarrow{\delta} H^q(G,A)$.

Tags: exact-sequence, group-cohomology

This is from P$570$ of Rotman's 'Intro to Homological Algebra'.

$A^* = Hom_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}G, A)$ where A is a $G$-module and $G$ is a group. There is an imbedding $i: A\to Hom_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}G, A)$and an exact sequence of $G$-modules:

$0\to A \to A^* \to C \to 0$

We have an isomorphism as follows:
$H^{q-1}(G,C) \xrightarrow{\delta} H^q(G,A)$. Here $\delta$ is the connecting homomorphism of the long exact sequence.

Rotman states that the isomorphism is because $A^*$ is $G$-coinduced. However, there's no theorems ahead of this point that supports this argument. Is it because of Theorem 1.5.3 from here:
[https://www.math.ucla.edu/~sharifi/groupcoh.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Esharifi/groupcoh.pdf)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There seems to be a lot of important details omitted. What are $A$ and $C$, and how are they related?

Comment: adding this now! thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Co-induced modules $A^*$ are acyclic for group cohomology: $H^q(G,A^*)=0$ for $q\ge1$.

Part of the long exact sequence of cohomology here is
$$H^{q-1}(G,A^*)\to H^{q-1}(G,C)\stackrel\delta\to H^{q}(G,A)\to H^{q}(G,A^*).$$
For $q\ge2$ this reduces to
$$0\to H^{q-1}(G,C)\stackrel\delta\to H^{q}(G,A)\to0$$
which means that $\delta$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I'm a bone head! You are the best, Angina! You've helped me many times! Would you please enlighten me on this one:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3784100/each-u-in-mathbbzg-otimes-mathbbzas-has-a-unique-expression-sigma-x